# How to populate the Room database?

Tags: android, database, kotlin, android-room

I have a list of ready-made physical exercises and I want to add them to my application so that they are displayed.
I'm thinking of using the Room database, but how can I populate it?
Or perhaps there are other options for solving my problem?How to populate the Room database?

Answer (score 0):

You'll a Data Access Object (DAO) and a Insert method.

It's worth taking a look at documentation:
https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I do it
The file should be located in src->main->assets->aaa.db

```
Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(), AppDataBase.class,"xxx.db")
                .createFromAsset("aaa.db")
                .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                .build();
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**